# How to do Discretionary Access Control List (DACL) for .Net Security?

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, access-control

I am interesting in using a Discretionary Access Control List with Membership provided by .Net Security.

- Are there any implementations of this that exist in .Net or open source?
- Is there a way to use .Net security as a DACL?
- Does a custom solution have to be built?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check [The Security Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664771(PandP.50).aspx). i am not sure whether it implements DACL or not, but i am sure it is something very useful. It is part of Enterprise Library.